# Can't login for the second time because of JSESSIONID?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc

*I can only log in for the first time, and that's all. I can't logout. I tryed to delete JSESSIONID cookies, but they are always in browser? If i delete JSESSIONID by hands - everything work perfectly.*

*this is my security-context.xml*

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/adm/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/red/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_REDADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/cus/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/index" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="email"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="UserDetailsServiceImplementation"
    class="com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.business.service.UserDetailsServiceImplementation">
    <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userFilter" class="com.softserveinc.ita.redplatform.web.filters.UserFilter">
    <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />


<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDetailsServiceImplementation">
     <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

*Login controller class*

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final ModelAndView login(
    @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false)final String error) {

Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .getAuthentication();

if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {

    /* The user is logged in :) */
    return new ModelAndView("forward:/index");
}

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

if (error != null) {
    model.addObject("error", "Invalid username or password!");
}

model.setViewName("common/login");
return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String loginerror(final Model model) {
model.addAttribute("error", "true");
return "common/login";
}
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<!-- Spring Security --> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Strange... should work. Have you tried to create an entry point that invalidate the session?  ... using session.invalidate()

Comment: Hi, add inside the tag logout `logout-url="/logout"` and try to access /logout url